# libapache2-mod-fastcgi not available on Ubuntu 16.04 multiverse

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php7

I've been trying to install Apache and PHP7 FPM on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.06.  However the following library is not available

> E: Package 'libapache2-mod-fastcgi' has no installation candidate

I've uncommented the multiverse repos in /etc/apt/sources.list and updated the repo list.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse  
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse
```

But I'm still not able to find that package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package you are looking for is not in the `xenial-security` repository, it's in the Multiverse component of the core Ubuntu repository for Xenial.

From `rmadison`, a tool that can be used to get information about what packages exist in what repositories/components from the Ubuntu repository data, we can determine both the Repository and Component in which the package exists (`xenial/Multiverse` indicates it is in the core `xenial` repository, not the `xenial-security` one):

```
 libapache2-mod-fastcgi | 2.4.7~0910052141-1   | precise/multiverse | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 libapache2-mod-fastcgi | 2.4.7~0910052141-1.1 | trusty/multiverse  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 libapache2-mod-fastcgi | 2.4.7~0910052141-1.1 | vivid/multiverse   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 libapache2-mod-fastcgi | 2.4.7~0910052141-1.2 | wily/multiverse    | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 libapache2-mod-fastcgi | 2.4.7~0910052141-1.2 | xenial/multiverse  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 libapache2-mod-fastcgi | 2.4.7~0910052141-1.2 | yakkety/multiverse | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
```

You need to edit the `xenial` line of your `sources.list` to enable the Multiverse repository.  You may wish to also enabled Multiverse on `xenial-updates` and `xenial-security` so you get security and general updates.  (You may omit the `xenial-updates` if you want only security updates, but note you can introduce breakages if the Apache version changes in one repo but not the other)

Comment: Once I added the following line to the /etc/apt/sources.list file I was able to find the package, thanks! ->
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse

Comment: @Eko3alpha Glad to have been able to help!